# What kind of marker should I use on a flip-mat battlemat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-beginner-box

I've ordered a [Pathfinder Beginner Box](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/products/beginnerbox). It contains a "Flip-mat" battlemat, which can supposedly work with markers. But what kind of marker should I use? Are they included in the box? If not, should I use a regular pencil or a special marker? Is it expensive?

Please be as precise as possible, I don't want to ruin it because I'll share it with my group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is the style of battle map found [here](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8oto?GameMastery-FlipMat-Basic) then the markers I see used most often(and with best results), are wet erase style. However the website does list as any marker being usable.

Looking at the beginner box page, it seems like it uses the above battle map, but since I don't actually own it, I can't say 100%

Answer (score 7):

Paizo claims even permanent markers (Sharpie) will come off if you draw over it with a dry-erase marker first.

http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2hgqy?FlipMat-Issues

I don't think I'd try permanent marker, but wet-erase and dry-erase are both proven options (according to Paizo reviews/threads).

Dry-erase can stain proper dry-erase boards when left long enough, and I've seen them leave permanent lines on laminated calendars when left for a month. The Flip-Mats are laminated paper, so wet-erase seems your best bet if you're concerned with permanent marks and you may not clean the mat right away.

Answer (score 1):

Personal experience answer here (I own the beginner box). The flip mat in mine is a semi-rigid glossy cardstock like material.

I use dry erase markers on mine. It wipes off easily.

I have also used permanent marker. The permanent market came off easily after writing over it with a dry erase marker.